# Nesting deferred calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Basically this is what I'm trying to do in pseudo-code:

```
Fetch AsyncResultA
  If Success
    Fetch 
      AsyncResultB
      AsyncResultC
    Either Success/Fails
      Display any successful results
  If Fails
    Display error
```

And this is what I've done in jQuery but it doesn't work:

```
        $.when (

          fetchA()

        ).then (function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            return {
              xhrObject1: [data, textStatus, jqXHR],
              xhrObject2: fetchB(),
              xhrObject3: fetchC(),
              xhrObject4: fetchD()
            }

          }, fail

        ).always( displayResults );
```

Notes:

All `fetch` functions are AJAX calls.

`displayResults` would get the successful fetched data and displays it all at once. So as long as `fetchA` succeeds, something would display.

`fail` would only get called when `fetchA` fails, thus canceling any further fetches.

Comment: just a side note. Use Kris Kowal's Q library for promises.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not returning a promise from the `.then` callback. Use `$.when` and return its return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are not returning a promise from the `.then` callback, but an ordinary object. That has the effect that `displayResults` is basically called on the original promise returned by `fetchA` instead. The relevant part from the [**documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (emphasis mine):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise [...]. These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can **return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks**.

Use `$.when` and return its return value:

```
fetchA().then(function () {
    return $.when([].slice.call(arguments), fetchB(), fetchC(), fetchD());
}, fail).always( displayResults );
```

`$.when` returns a promise that is resolved when all the promises passed to itself are resolved (or rejected). Therefore is no reason to use `$.when` if you only pass a single argument to it.

If you don't want to execute `displayResults` when `fetchA` fails, you can bind the fail handler separately:

```
fetchA().fail(fail).then(function () {
    return $.when([].slice.call(arguments), fetchB(), fetchC(), fetchD());
}).always( displayResults );
```

Comment: Thanks @Felix-Kling for your quick reply! This makes more sense. Although `FetchA` doesn't seem to pass its results to `displayResults`. I tried adding an argument to the then function but it doesn't seem to work either..

Comment: Oh, I get what you wanted to do with the `xhrObject1: [data, textStatus, jqXHR]` part... updating. That should work now.